# What does the question mark mean in this piece of code?

Tags: javascript

What does the question mark mean in this piece of code?

```
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
    function reload(form)
    {
        var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
        self.location='dd.php?cat=' + val;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It indicates the start of a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in a URI.

Since it is part of a string, it holds no special significance for the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

`?` in url, indicates the `QueryString.`

so `dd.php>cat=val` defines -- `dd.php` the `webpage url` `?cat=val` defines the `QueryString`

`cat` is a `key` in `QueryString`, and `val` is the `value` for cat QueryString key

Answer (score 0):

The `?` on a url denotes the start of a query string that can be used for a `GET` request. This allows parameters to be passed to the server which can be used in obtaining a response, among other things.

Comment: The user of query strings is not exclusive to GET requests.

Comment: @Quentin - Hence, why I said *among other things*. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: — That's in a different sentence. You are saying "Things other than a response", not "Things other than a GET request".

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks for telling me what I am saying. No where did I say it can only be used in a GET request. I used that as an example, since it's the most common usage.